# Android: Maintain the last viewed position in ListView

Tags: android, listview, pagination, listviewitem

i completed the top pagination like

```
messagesContainer.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                if (visibleItemCount == totalItemCount){
                    java.lang.System.out.println("too little items to use a ScrollView!");
                } else {
                    if ((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) == totalItemCount) {
                        //Log.e("bottomPosition", "bottomPosition");

                    }else if (firstVisibleItem == 0) {
                        Log.e("topPosition", "topPosition");



                            index = messagesContainer.getLastVisiblePosition();
                            View v = messagesContainer.getChildAt(messagesContainer.getHeaderViewsCount());
                            top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();



                        if(rechedTopPosition != null){

                            rechedTopPosition = null;

                                Log.e("pageNoForVolUrl", pageNoForVolUrl+"");

                                getPrevChatVolley();

                        }   


                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    //Log.e("a", "scrolling stopped..."); 
                }


            }
        });
```

---

```
for(int i = 0; i < rowsArray.length() ; i++){

    JSONObject singleObj = rowsArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject valueObj = singleObj.getJSONObject("value");

    String commentId = valueObj.getString("_id");
    String textMessage = valueObj.getString("body");





    ChatMessageItems chatMessage = new ChatMessageItems();
    chatMessage.setId(122);//dummy
    chatMessage.setMessageId(commentId);
    chatMessage.setMessage(textMessage);

    if (fromUserId.equals("384")) {
        chatMessage.setMe(false); // False = right side, True = left side
    } else {
        chatMessage.setMe(true);
    }

    itemsAdapter.insert(chatMessage, 0);

}

    rechedTopPosition = "fulFilled";

    messagesContainer.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

---

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/messagesContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
```

By using this code i'm able to add the list view items at the top but it's not maintaining the last viewed position

For ex:

My initial listView is like

```
----
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

When i scroll to 15 (top) position it is loading all items at top but it's not maintaining the last viewed 15 item position. It showing the some other item after updating the listView. So, i want to maintain the last viewed position after updating the items at top position. Please give me any idea...... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Declare `Parcelable state = null;`as globally to the present class
2. Inside of `onScroll` (Before calling the list view data method) store the position like

   `state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();`
3. After appending the list view data into adapter maintain the position like

   `if(state != null){
       listView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
   }`

Answer (score 0):

You can get visible position of listview by:

```
int position;

YOURLISTVIEW.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
             position = firstVisibleItem;

        }
    });
```

then you can set position to your listview by:

```
YOURLISTVIEW.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: It's not working. If i'm using this, all pages are loading at a time when i scroll to top position